# Looking for a value within a list object in a dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I am looking for a value within a list object in a DataFrame:

This is my code:

```
for tags in Questions["Tags"]:
    if "deep-learning" in tags:
        Questions["DL-flag"] = 1
```

The column that I am looking into looks like this:
*[python, keras, tensorflow, cnn, probability]*

According to my code looking for **deep-learning** in that example should result in **false**, but that is not what is happening, since all the column is returning **true** for each row

Could you help me out?

Comment: Putting lists into pandas "cells" is almost certainly a mistake before you do anything else

Comment: provide a full reproducible example of the dataframe and the matching expected output

Comment: The whole pandas model is based on scalars. Not to mention that you now have O(NxM) search complexity here running in python time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `Questions["DL-flag"] = 1` only puts `1` in every row of `DL-flag` and that explains` your observation.

This is how you can achieve your goal:

```
Questions['DL-flag'] = Questions['Tags'].apply(lambda l: 'deep-learning' in l)
```

You `apply` this `lambda l: 'deep-learning' in l` function over every element of the `Series` `Questions['Tags']`

Comment: Hello Raymond, In your code you are substituting 1 for the tag.  In my case I want to flag the row 1 if the “deep learning” is the list.

Comment: Substituting? I am confused because the results should be filled into a new column called `DL-flag`.

Comment: I had not been able to see the whole function since I was seeing on my phone.  I tried and it worked perfectly!!  Thank you Raymond!!